# When I compile PECL imagick using phpize, I get the error "undefined macro: _m4_divert_diversion

Tags: php, imagick, pecl, phpize

When I download the source of PECL imagick and compile it using phpize
I get an error "undefined macro: _m4_divert_diversion".

- CentOS6.7
- PHP7.3
- autoconf 2.71 → 2.69
- m4 1.4.13 → 1.4.18
- libtool 2.2.6b

```
wget htps://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.7.0.tgz
tar -xzvf imagick-3.7.0.tgz
cd imagick-3.7.0

sudo /usr/local/php7.3/bin/phpize

Configuring for:
PHP Api Version 20180731
Zend Module Api No: 20180731
Zend Extention Api No: 320180731
build/libtool.m4:274: error: m4_defn: undefined macro: _m4_divert_diversion
build/libtool.m4:274: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
```

File with error
build/libtool.m4:274

```
AC_DEFUN(_LT_AC_TRY_LINK, [　←Line274
cat > conftest.$ac_ext <<EOF
dnl This sometimes fails to find confdefs.h, for some reason.
dnl [#]line __oline__ "[$]0"
[#]line __oline__ "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
int main() {
; return 0; }
EOF
```

I have changed the versions of autoconf and m4 to 2.69 and 1.4.18 respectively, but the error has not changed.

I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there is something suspicious.

Comment: It works without a hitch here (not centos) - the only difference to your setup wrt/ the tools being the libtool version - can you update that? (2.4.6 running here)

Comment: @TomRegner Thank you for your comment.
I have updated libtool to 2.4.6, but the error is still there.